# listening and pronunciation of contractions, 'd

Tags: contractions, phonology, fast-speech-rules

I can't exactly hear the sound of 'd in cassettes, like:
    She'd make it.
    She'd be with them very soon.

I tried to listen them in youtube. I found I could hear it when some native english speakers speak slowly and clearly. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzhjD-XrYjg) But in another video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSSM8mBq3TI), the sound of 'd doesn't seem to be pronounced. (Is it right?)

I want to ask if native english speakers  pronounce and hear the sound of 'd in conversation?

Thanks.

Comment: The guy in the second video is a hair weird, and is overdoing it a bit, but mostly he is pronouncing the "d".  Note, for instance, that "I'd" is pronounced pretty much like "eyed", as in "She eyed the stranger suspiciously."  "It'd" is the oddest one to pronounce, and you're forgiven if you can't quite manage it -- give it time.

Comment: *It'd* is such a weird word. You can pronounce it *idded* but I think native speakers usually just say *id*.

Comment: Leave Shane alone.  Stick with Rachel.  Note some people articulate things very clearly and will pronounce the D beautifully every time, others won't.  But I don't understand what you're asking about "cassettes".  There's no D sound in that word.

Comment: I mean I listen to the cassettes and can't hear the "'d" sound every time.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, most speakers don't pronounce this *d* clearly. It's often dropped entirely.

When I say *I'd drop it* it sounds exactly like *I drop it* unless I'm making an effort to enunciate. Likewise *I'd just go* is indistinguishable from *I just go*. I think this is typical.

The *d* is clearest when it's followed by a vowel. When I say *I'd ask*, my tongue briefly touches the roof of the mouth. You can hear it slightly interrupt the flow of air. When I say *I ask* there is no obstruction of air at all, and the *I* sound blends seamlessly with the short *a* sound.